# Unable to conect OpenLDAP with TLS on CentOS

Tags: centos, ssl, openssl, openldap

This is the error log:
[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMeip.png)

[cn=config.ldif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Tge1.png)

I have tried almost every single configuration possible of ldap.conf
[current config of ldap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54IkF.png)

I tried this : https://www.golinuxcloud.com/configure-openldap-with-tls-certificates/#comment-20414
as well this : https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/configure-openldap-with-ssl-on-centos-7-rhel-7.html

I also updated ca in centos but nothing seem to work.
Please guide me with this I am totally new to openldap.

Comment: Please test the connection with `openssl s_client` and see what it says.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to check.  Is slapd even running.

```
ps aux | grep slapd
```

if it's running, see what ports it is bound to

```
netstat -an
```

check /etc/sysconfig/slapd and make sure that you have at least:

```
SLAPD_URLS="ldapi:/// ldap:/// ldaps:///"
```